# Socket.io Respond to single user

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

When user visit my webpage his is connected to socket on port 3000

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

Now I included this code so every page have it. How is there a way to pass second parameter here so even if user refresh page or go to a different page he still have some unique identifier ? My problem is that I got node.js app that respond to event.

```
    socket.on('myevent', function (data) {
    Some code is executed here.....
```

Well now I want to emit response back to the single user who sent it, but what if in meantime user decide to refresh or switch page ? That will give him new connection.

Comment: You need to create a session for the user

Comment: @Musa What do you mean exactly ?